# Pasar dos dator de la etiqueta option de un select

Tags: atributos

Lo que necesito es pasar dos valores de la de la etiqueta option a parte de su text lo que se me ocurrió fue que al atributo value pasarle los valores como un array algo así pero no me funciona.

```
<option value="[valor1,valor2]" >texto</option>
```

Comment: No nos muestras como pasas los valores. Amplía el código editando la pregunta para evaluar el contexto general y no solo la línea del option.

Comment: No tiene mucho sentido, al menos yo no se verlo, hacer corresponder un texto con dos valores en un option.  Usando el select de HTML puedes poner el atributo `multiple` y en sus `option` asignar los valores de forma individual a cada texto correspondiente y así seguro que se envian como array si son seleccionados varios.

Comment: En caso que desees sí o sí que una opción comprenda un conjunto de otras opciones, no es en el HTML donde debes intentar poner el array, sino en el código que reciba dicho formulario. Es decir, si quieres una opcion que comprenda la opcion con valor 1 y la opcion con valor 3, puedes poner 1-3 como valor y luego leerlo en tu script del servidor de forma adecuada con explode por ejemplo (si es PHP).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No es posible pasar un array de valores como value en un option ya que este siempre se recibe como string, es decir aún si se le pasa value="[1,2]" lo que se recibe es un string "[1,2]", lo que puedes hacer es pasar los valores separados por coma o cualquier otro separador de preferencia y luego al capturarlos crear un array con **split** usando el separador elegido.

Ejemplo:

**HTML**

```
<select name="lista" id="lista">
  <option value="hola,chau">saludo</option>
  <option value="2,3">numeros</option>
</select>
```

**JS:**

```
const lista = document.getElementById("lista");
lista.addEventListener("click", () => {
console.log(lista.value.split(","));
});
```

Esto devolvería: array **['hola', 'chau']** o array **[1, 2]** al seleccionar un option o el otro.

Comment: Claro entiendo lo que pasa es que lo que necesito es pasarle a una lista tres valores obtenida de la bases de datos en mi caso necesito pasarle en el el value el id del dato en el text le paso el nombre y necesito pasar el precio para manipularlo y en base a eso mostra el resultado en un imput.